# fetching each item inside an array and collect all results in one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to get for each bird an own response from the API but unfortunately b2 replaces the cards of the first run with b1 / first bird after.
I want to be able to see the response of b1 and b2 both on the website. As it is now, b2 replaces all cards from b1.

my code:

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MyContainer from './MyContainer';

function App() {
  
  const [a, seta] = useState(null)
  const [animals, setanimals] = useState([])
  var birds = ["b1","b2"];
  var response;
  const getanimalData = async () => {
    if (!a) return;

    const allResponse = await Promise.all(
      birds.map(async (item) => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.testapicleared`);
        var data = await response.json();
        setanimals(data.items)
      })
    );
    
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='text'>
        Connected-bird: {a}
      </div>
      
         birdies
      
      <MyContainer animals={animals}/>
    </div>
  );
```

MyContainer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import animalCard from './animalCard'
const MyContainer = ({ animals }) => {
    return (     
    <div className='animal-container'> 
        {animals.map((animal, index) => {
            
            return <animalCard animal={animal} key={index}/>
        })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyContainer
```

animalCard.js

```
import React from 'react'

const animalCard = ({ animal }) => {
  
    <div>
            
        animal name: {animal.meta.name}
        </div> 
} 

export default animalCard
```

Comment: Promise.all returns an array of the values, so just update your state after the promise.all has been finished.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Also, you are overriding your state with each `setanimals` call. What you'd want is `setanimals([...animals, data.items]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getanimalData = async () => {
    if (!a) return;

    const allResponse = await Promise.all(birds.map(item => fetch(`https://api.testapicleared`)))

    const allResponseJson = await Promise.all(allResponse.map(response => response.json()))

    setAnimals(lastAnimals => [...lastAnimals,...allResponseJson.map(animal => animal.items).flat()]
}
```

Comment: thanks but now I have an object with 2 arrays. How can I change the animals.map in myContainer to create a card for each object for each element in each array?

Comment: `const MyContainer = ({ animals }) => {
    return (     
<div> 
        {animal.map((ObjectElement) => {
            
            
            ObjectElement.map((animal, index) => {
             
                return <animalcard animal={animal} key={index}/>        
        })}
     )}
    </div>
  )
}`
Idk what is wrong
@justanotherguy

Comment: `but now I have an object with 2 arrays.` - I suppose It's the `animal.items` what you mean. I don`t know what animal.items is so I can't tell you. I just followed what you were doing in your example. Pls update your question containing what you have done and what output you get.

Comment: `/////NEW
          const getanimalData = async () => {
            if (!a) return;
        
            const allResponse = await Promise.all(
              birds.map(item => { fetch(`https://api.testapicleared`);
        const allResponseJson = await Promise.all(allResponse.map(response => response.json()))
        setanimals(lastAnimals => [...lastAnimals,...allResponseJson.map(animal=>animal.items)]);
              })
            );
    ////NEW`

Comment: https://ibb.co/sqBJ0KF  AllResponseJSON

Comment: Add `.flat()` after the map in the setState as my update. It should work.